# aapt error: Archive is toast

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, groovy, aapt

When running certain builds on Jenkins, I have been getting this error and I can't seem to figure out how to prevent this from happening. So far my only work around for this is deleting the entire Jenkins workspace.

Any suggestions on a cleaner solution to this problem? And what does this error mean?

> E/zip     (57580): **error during crunch - archive is toast**
>       **ERROR: failed opening/creating 'debug.apk' as Zip** file:mobile:generateAPKs FAILED
>
> Process 'command '/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error occurs when using the `AAPT` tool to add or remove files from the APK. Since APKs are zips anyways, you can use any zip tool to add or remove files.

To delete a file use the command `zip -d yourAPKFile.apk theFileYouWantToRemove`

To add a file use the command `zip youAPKFile.apk theFileYouWantToAdd`

Alternatively, you can can just remove the files using the `zip` command and add them using the AAPT tool.